# Run bash command in Cygwin from another application

Tags: c++, python, windows, cygwin

From a windows application written on C++ or python, how can I execute arbitrary shell commands?

My installation of Cygwin is normally launched from the following bat file:

```
@echo off

C:
chdir C:\cygwin\bin

bash --login -i
```

Comment: I would like to do something similar but I didn't find out any possibility, it would be useful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Python, run bash with `os.system`, `os.popen` or `subprocess` and pass the appropriate command-line arguments.

```
os.system(r'C:\cygwin\bin\bash --login -c "some bash commands"')
```

Comment: can you give me some example of this program?

Comment: No, my command didn't execute os.system(r"C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe -c \"~/project1/make\"")

Comment: I just tried it myself and found that I needed to add `--login` to the bash command line. I've amended my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The following function will run Cygwin's Bash program while making sure the bin directory is in the system path, so you have access to non-built-in commands. This is an alternative to using the login (-l) option, which may redirect you to your home directory.

```py
def cygwin(command):
    """
    Run a Bash command with Cygwin and return output.
    """
    # Find Cygwin binary directory
    for cygwin_bin in [r'C:\cygwin\bin', r'C:\cygwin64\bin']:
        if os.path.isdir(cygwin_bin):
            break
    else:
        raise RuntimeError('Cygwin not found!')
    # Make sure Cygwin binary directory in path
    if cygwin_bin not in os.environ['PATH']:
        os.environ['PATH'] += ';' + cygwin_bin
    # Launch Bash
    p = subprocess.Popen(
        args=['bash', '-c', command],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    p.wait()
    # Raise exception if return code indicates error
    if p.returncode != 0:
        raise RuntimeError(p.stderr.read().rstrip())
    # Remove trailing newline from output
    return (p.stdout.read() + p.stderr.read()).rstrip()
```

Example use:

```
print cygwin('pwd')
print cygwin('ls -l')
print cygwin(r'dos2unix $(cygpath -u "C:\some\file.txt")')
print cygwin(r'md5sum $(cygpath -u "C:\another\file")').split(' ')[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Bash should accept a command from args when using the -c flag:

```
C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe -c "somecommand"
```

Combine that with C++'s [`exec`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_execvp.htm) or python's `os.system` to run the command.

Comment: i think that i must run new process of Cygwin in my python application, because: http://i.imgur.com/Anfla.png