# Need to write python script to execute linux commands in cygwin

Tags: python, linux, shell

I need to write a python script to automate some repetitive Linux commands. (Given to me by someone using mac) The commands are mostly mkdir and a htk speech recognition kit commands. I need to execute these commands on cygwin. I tried searching for tutorials on how to do this but don't think I found a right one yet. I'm pretty new to python.

Comment: What have you tried? [Did you go here (Python Docs)?](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/)

Comment: Hi, yes I did. I can code in basic python. But I'm not sure how to execute linux commands in cygwin

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513133/run-bash-command-in-cygwin-from-another-application

Comment: Are you running cygwin Python, or native Windows python? (Also, I assume you mean you want to execute some cygwin commands, not linux commands. Unless you're using cygwin to ssh to some remote linux box or something?)

Comment: Hi abarnert, I'm running native Windows Python and yes, I want to execute cygwin commands

Comment: @Christopher, I'm not sure what the bat file is on the link you posted. Can I do it without the bat file? Sorry, I'm a teen and I'm new =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I use python as a shell replacement, my import section usually looks like this:

```
from os import mkdir, chdir
from shutil import move, copy, rmtree, copytree
from subprocess import call
```

This gives me the ability to move and copy files and directories as well as make new directories and delete directories.  If you want to call programs on the shell instead of with the python functions, use `call` from the `subprocess` module.

```
# To run the program foo that takes an option and two arguments
# Equivalent to "foo -d bar baz" directly in the shell
call(['foo', '-d', 'bar', 'baz'])
```

You would use `call` for the htk stuff.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was what I was exactly looking for! If possible, Any reference to where you learnt this would be appreciated, or else, it's alright! =)

Comment: [shutil](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html), [os](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html), and [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)