# Running a bash file with Python

Tags: python, bash, cygwin, popen

I've got a bash file that I normally execute using Cygwin. 
I need to run this file from my Python code.

I tried this:

```
for bashfile in files:
    p = Popen(bashfile, cwd=dname) #dname is the current directory of the script
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

I've also seen a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513133/run-bash-command-in-cygwin-from-another-application), but when trying to run it that way it says that it can't find the directory of my bash file...

Any ideas? Thanks! :-)

**Edit:** `bashfile` has a full path.

Comment: where is you script located and where are you bash files located?

Comment: The bash file is in one of the subdirecotories of the script's directory. The point is that they're in different places. Does it matter?

Comment: If `bashfile` is just the name of the script (e.g. `foo.sh`), try specifying the path to the script ... `./subdir/foo.sh`.

Comment: Could you provide the full error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need its output to get it directly to Python? If not this may be very fast and easy solution:

```
os.system("""here some code you use to execute in Terminal""")
```

Comment: you can always check `os.getcwd()` and even change it to some other via `os.chdir("/foo")`

Comment: if you decide for os.system, this example may be useful: http://superuser.com/questions/513315/create-a-term-document-matrix-from-files/667924#667924

Comment: Thanks so much @andi! That weird solution in the link I gave completely confused me... thanks so much, works now! :-)

Comment: @Cheshie: I don't understand. How `os.system(bashfile)` can possibly work if `Popen(bashfile, cwd=dname)` can't find `bashfile`?

Comment: I wrote `os.system(sh bashfile)`. Was I supposed to do that with Popen as well...? (sorry if it's a silly mistake, I don't really know too much about this stuff...).

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this, though it does (and will no matter what you try) matter where the directory is. This, as far as the output goes, may be a little bit cleaner than the `os` method.

```
import commands
cmd="bash ./script.sh"
commands.getoutput(cmd)
```

If the case is that you need to change the directory:

```
cmd = "/path/to/your/script/script.sh"
```

The added benefit of using this method, versus say, `os` is that you can assign the output to a variable...

```
fun_times = commands.getoutput("bash ./script.sh")
```

whereas...

```
not_fun_times = os.system("./script.sh")
```

will throw an error.

etc, etc.

Comment: Thanks, but: `"'{' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\noperable program or batch file."` ? You're solution looks like I could get the output into Python, but I don't understand the error...

Comment: Where is there a `{`?

Comment: No idea... I tested it on a script whose content is: `echo "hello"` or something like that...

Comment: Can you give the full error? Because it works perfectly fine on my end.

Comment: I gave you the full error. The code I wrote was as you said: `import commands // cmd="bash C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Desktop/hi.sh" // commands.getoutput(cmd)` (I added the "//" to separate between lines here).

Comment: That's weird. You might want to try it without the term `bash` after `cmd=`. It's not totally necessary and *might* be an issue. Other than that, I have no idea why it would throw that error as long as your path specification is syntactically correct.

Comment: Nope, still same error... (sorry :( ). I'm using Python 2.7 with IDLE. Does that have to do with anything? Thanks... (and I think that SO is about to kick us out of here 'cause we're writing too many comments ;) ).

Comment: One last comment then! Just try it on your command line. If it works, you know it was `IDLE`

Comment: Oops, I didn't mean to be rude (sorry!). Anyway, I tried it on the command line (with and without "bash"), and I still get the same error. I guess I'll use andi's solution and write the output into a file... Thanks Matt, I really appreciate your help (I upvoted :) ).